# How can i work out if my SharePoint 2010 has a Report Server set up?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I have been given a SharePoint 2010 environment, and wanting to know if a report server has been set up. Is there anyway I can tell?
When I go to Set server defaults in General Application settings under Reporting Services it gives me `This functionality is not supported because a Report Server URL has not been specified in Central Administration` error.
On the SQL server a Reporting Services Config manager has been set up and there is a `ReportServer` folder in `14/isapi` and same for on the SharePoint app server. But when I try and access the web service URL it gives an error to the jist of `specified file can be found Microsoft.SharePoint or one of its dependencies` so I want to check if a server has actually been set up. Or is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest going to central admin -> Manage service applications. You should expect to see a service application with a type of "SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application"

Another option is to run the following powershell:

```
get-spserviceinstance -all |where {$_.TypeName -like "SQL Server Reporting*"}
```

It is possible someone took some of the steps to start configuring this and never finished.

If you see the service application, click on it and see if the settings are correct for your environment.